# unable to get data from json for comparing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/9/). I am basically trying to create [a similar demo  app](http://currency.fullstacks.net/) for learning jquery with json 
I am stuck  in "how to  calculate the currencies values by reading data from the `localStorage`?
can anyone tel me steps to achieve this target?"

eg. if i type USD value as 1 then on another textbox the corresponding currency amount should be converted

i have Jason data obtained by calling remote websites as below

```
{
    "list": {
        "meta": {
            "type": "resource-list",
            "start": 0,
            "count": 168
        },
        "resources": [{
                "resource": {
                    "classname": "Quote",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": "USD/KRW",
                        "price": "1062.280029",
                        "symbol": "KRW=X",
                        "ts": "1396294510",
                        "type": "currency",
                        "utctime": "2014-03-31T19:35:10+0000",
                        "volume": "0"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "resource": {
                    "classname": "Quote",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": "SILVER 1 OZ 999 NY",
                        "price": "0.050674",
                        "symbol": "XAG=X",
                        "ts": "1396287757",
                        "type": "currency",
                        "utctime": "2014-03-31T17:42:37+0000",
                        "volume": "217"
                    }
                }
            }


        ]
    }
}
```

### JavaScript from fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    yahoo_getdata(); 
});
    function yahoo_getdata() {   
    var a = new Date();
    var b = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json&random=" + a.getTime() + "&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(b, function (e) {
        if (e) {
            console.log(e);
            var d = {};
            d.time = a.getTime();
            d.data = e;    
            localStorage.setItem('all_currencies',JSON.stringify(d));
            var jsonStringFromLS = localStorage.getItem('all_currencies');
            console.log(JSON.parse(jsonStringFromLS));
        }
    });

}
/*
* On keyup on any textfield, the respected currencies should be calculated and should display on respective textboxes...
 "add more textbox" feature i will do by myself after learning the above technique
*/
//----when typed in any of these 3 textbox then convert money----------
$( "#amount1" ).keyup(function() {
    var currency1=$( "#currency1" ).val();
    var currency2=$( "#currency2" ).val();
    $("#amount2").val("2.3");   //
    $("#amount3").val("59.34"); 
});
```

Is here anybody to shed light on me?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about the problem?

Comment: @ilyai when i enter any value in the textbox then it should convert value by taking it from  stored json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one place you hav to iterate over the resources in the JSON, find those you are interestet in and take the 'price'-value which you then need for the calculations.

In your function yahoo_getdata() you have the parameter e which contains the data. So you could do the following:

```
var i, l, r, c;
r = e.list.resources;
for (i = 0, l = r.length; i < l; i += 1) {
  c = r[i].resource.fields;
  switch (c.name) {
    case 'USD/KRW':
      // store c.price somewhere so you can later access it for the calculation
      break;
    // more case for other currencies you may need
  }
}
```

Comment: The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/10/ The calculations are wrong but you should get the idee.

Comment: thankyou! now i understood what you was explaining me above, but still the basic part is not done & not enough for my brain to understand. It will be easily understood if you update your fiddle for last time. All test boxes aren't functioning properly!!!

Comment: so you are not happy to help me further ?

Comment: I updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/11/). Its up to you to implement funtions to convert from amount2 to 1 and 3 and from amount3 to 1 and 2. Also there should be a handler when the Selectboxes change. But this was not part of the question.

Comment: @phylax Hi! Can you help me, why the updated Fiddle by you is not working now? http://jsfiddle.net/AZnQp/11/